# Spring boot 3 endpoint 404

Tags: java, spring-boot

When I call the endpoint, I receive a 404 error. The problem may be that the annotation SpringBootApplication cannot find the controller.

For information I use spring-boot 3.2 and IDE intellij.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class TaskManagementApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TaskManagementApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/users")
public class UserController {

    private final UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    public UserController(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }
}
```

[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKsBh.png)

I tried this, but it didn't work.

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.other.packages","com.other"})
```

Comment: As presented, the controller has no endpoints

Comment: Add a method to your controller with for example a `@GetMapping` annotation that returns the data you want the web service to return.

Comment: Which endpoint are you calling? i dont see any defined on your controller.